# How to query firebase with orderByChild and startAt the parent key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is how my data are stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc4Bg.png)

[image]
What I want is to query all obj ordering by their rank value but starting at a specific obj let's say obj2.

So the result I'm waiting is [obj3, obj2, obj4]

How can't I achieved that.

Thanks !!

Comment: Are your keys exactly like what is shown in the question? I'm asking as *a specific object* is a little vague... In this case when you get to obj10, it will actually follow obj1 (obj1, obj10, obj2 etc). So that would cause the ordering to change and loose track of *a specific object*. Perhaps you can expand the question with a more clear example or even a use case so we can come up with an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you also know the rank of `obj2` that can be accomplished with:

```
ref.orderByChild("rank").startAt(10, 'obj2')
```

Knowing the rank of `obj2` (`10` in the line above) is required though, you can't do this without knowing that value.

---

**v9/modular API**: Since some folks seem to land on this answer while looking for how to perform a query with the modular API of SDK version 9 and later, that'd be:

```
query(ref, orderByChild("rank"), startAt(10, 'obj2'))
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: How  would this be written for Firebase 9? I can't seem to get `orderByChild` working together with `startAt`.

Comment: I have the same problem. How does it work in firebase 9?

Comment: I added an example of how this translates to the v9 API. If that doesn't work for you, please post new question.